# Can't get "div" to float properly

Tags: css, css-float

[image]

I'm having trouble setting up my css to display my page correctly.  I want the "DRINKS" icon to remain on the left, but i want to shift up the entire block of drink images to the right of the "DRINKS" icon.

I tried floating the drinks icon to the left, then floating the block of drink images to the left too, but it obviously didnt work.

HTML:

```
        <div id="drink_section">

            <img src="/{{MEDIA_URL}}images/images/drinks_order_title.png" alt="" id="drinks_order_title" />                   

            <div id="drink_menu">
                {% for item in drink %}
                    <div id="drink_set">
                        <img src="{{item.photo_menu.url}}" alt="" id="drink_photo" />
                        <img src="/{{MEDIA_URL}}images/images/drinks_title_overlay.png" alt="" id="drinks_title_overlay" />                   
                        <p id="drink_name">{{item.name}}</p> 
                        <p id="drink_price">${{item.price}}</p>

                        <div id="drink_footer">
                            <a id ="drink_order_button" href="{{item.slug}}"></a>
                        </div><!-- end drink_footer-->

                    </div><!-- end drink_set-->
                {% endfor %}
            </div><!-- end drink_menu--> 

        </div><!-- end drink_section-->
```

CSS

```
#drink_section{
    width:755px;
    float:left;

}

#drink_menu{
    float:left;
}

#drink_title{
    float:left;
    width:128px;
}

#drink_set{
    float:left;
    width:137px;
}
```

Comment: WHICH entire block of drink images to the right of WHICH "DRINKS" icon.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/8As3FbuX)***

Hi now you can change your code and used `ul li` list item for this design

as like this

**html**

```
<ul class="ordr">
  <li>
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/772707aec2cb2ce7b372deb2d4e06b51?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="">
    <p>price tag</p>
    <a href="#">price tag</a>
  </li>
<li>
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/772707aec2cb2ce7b372deb2d4e06b51?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="">
    <p>price tag</p>
    <a href="#">price tag</a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/772707aec2cb2ce7b372deb2d4e06b51?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="">
    <p>price tag</p>
    <a href="#">price tag</a>
  </li>
    <li>
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/772707aec2cb2ce7b372deb2d4e06b51?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="">
    <p>price tag</p>
    <a href="#">price tag</a>
  </li>
      <li>
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/772707aec2cb2ce7b372deb2d4e06b51?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="">
    <p>price tag</p>
    <a href="#">price tag</a>
  </li>
        <li>
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/772707aec2cb2ce7b372deb2d4e06b51?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="">
    <p>price tag</p>
    <a href="#">price tag</a>
  </li>
          <li>
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/772707aec2cb2ce7b372deb2d4e06b51?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="">
    <p>price tag</p>
    <a href="#">price tag</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**css**

```
.ordr{
  list-style:none;}
.ordr li{
float:left;
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  margin-left:1px;
  position:relative;
}
.ordr li img{
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px black;}

.ordr li p{
position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:66px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/z28wenJO)***

Comment: Use fire bug a Firefox add one, it will help you too much in such issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
  #drink_section{
        width:755px;
        float:left;
        **display:inline-block;**

    }

    #drink_menu{
        float:left;
    }

    #drink_title{
        float:left;
        width:128px;
    }

    #drink_set{
        float:left;
        **width:400px;** /* more width than current */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the following to the images section.

```
float:right;
```

Answer (score 1):

try to make  **#drink_set** width 100px i think it will help you

```
#drink_set{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
```